# Windows Common File Dialog Will Not Display While Running in Visual Studio 2010 Debugger

Tags: windows, user-interface, mfc, dialog

I have a VS2010 C++ application that uses the Windows Common File Dialog in a pretty ordinary fashion.  My company just updated my workstation to a nice quad core CPU with Windows 7 whereas my previous system was still running XP.  When I run my application inside the Visual Studio debugger, any attempt to call the CFD seems to fail silently with the code throwing no apparant errors to the output window, and no dialog appearing.  Outside the debugger things work just fine.  I invoke the dialog pretty much the same way every time.

```
CString theFilterList = "CSV Import Files (*.csv)|*.csv";
theFilterList = theFilterList + "|All files (*.*)|*.*||";
// construct the common dialog
CFileDialog fileDlg(TRUE, NULL, NULL,OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST |     OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT, theFilterList,this);
POSITION pos;
// Initialize m_ofn structure
fileDlg.m_ofn.lpstrTitle = "Please select a UP supplied CSV file to prepare to load into SCT.";

// Create buffer for file names.
const DWORD bufferSize = (MAX_MULTISELECT_FILENAMES * MAX_FILENAMESIZE) + 1;
TCHAR* filenamesBuffer = new TCHAR[bufferSize];

// Initialize beginning and end of buffer.
filenamesBuffer[0] = NULL;
filenamesBuffer[bufferSize-1] = NULL;

// Attach buffer to OPENFILENAME member.
fileDlg.m_ofn.lpstrFile = filenamesBuffer;
fileDlg.m_ofn.nMaxFile = bufferSize;

if ( fileDlg.DoModal() != IDOK)
    {
    theCSVFilenameList.RemoveAll();
return;
}

pos  = fileDlg.GetStartPosition();
while( pos )
    {
theCSVFilenameList.Add(fileDlg.GetNextPathName( pos ));
}
```

Comment: Roger, In my opinion there are no stupid questions so I appreciate the thought even though that is not it.  I'm proud (astounded; amazed) to say I've been coding for Windows since Windows 1.1 (oh the horror) My guess is that this old school style needs to be updated for Win 7+.  I miss the days when the technology guys ran MS instead of the marketing dept.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: So, what happens exactly, when you execute `fileDlg.DoModal()` line in the debugger? What is `DoModal` return value? Does it return immediately or hangs?

Comment: I just changed my code a bit so I could see the value - it appears to return IDCANCEL immediately without displaying the dialog first

' /*if (fileDlg.DoModal() != IDOK)
 {
 return;
   }*/

  int iResult = fileDlg.DoModal();

  if (iResult != IDOK )
   {
   return;
   }

Comment: There is something in the debugging environment that causes this behaviour. You need to debug `DoModal` using MFC source code. I didn't have such problems in Windows 7.

Comment: These dialogs can fail in hard to diagnose ways because they load shell extension handlers into your process.  Something you can easily see in the Output window, it displays load notifications for a bunch of DLLs.  A misbehaving one can cause random trouble.  Say, some kind of DRM component that doesn't like seeing a debugger attached.  Run SysInternals' AutoRuns utility and disable any shell extension handler that doesn't have a Microsoft copyright.  Narrow down the troublemaker with a binary search.

Comment: from [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xb6dhth(v=vs.100).aspx): if IDCANCEL is returned, call the [Windows CommDlgExtendedError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646916(v=vs.100).aspx) function to determine whether an error occurred

Comment: Is it possible that you run debug under a UNICODE configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem.  I found that my StackReserve size was too high.  I reduced it and the dialog started coming up.  Though in my case it was happening both in and out of the debugger.